# Consulta sql com ALIAS igual ao nome da coluna com retorno inesperado

Tags: mysql, sql, alias

Essa consulta

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(data,'%d/%m/%Y') AS ALIASdata
FROM departamentos
ORDER BY data DESC
```

me retorna as datas na ordem que eu quero

```
18/05/2020
17/04/2019
17/05/2018
17/03/2018
17/03/2015
17/03/2014
```

Se eu executo essa query, **com o ALIAS igual ao nome da coluna**

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(data,'%d/%m/%Y') AS data
FROM departamentos
ORDER BY data DESC
```

me retorna uma **ordem inesperada**

```
18/05/2020
17/05/2018
17/04/2019
17/03/2018
17/03/2015
17/03/2014
```

Porque isso acontece?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A questão não é o nome do alias ser igual ao nome da coluna.

O motivo é que DATE_FORMAT retorna uma string, e comparações de string são diferentes de comparações de data.

Uma forma simples de visualizar a diferença na comparação é imaginar que na comparação string a data vira um número só. Dessa forma, "17052018" é maior que "17042019".